# Compile a GWT project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to compile the StackWatcher example, but after selecting "GWT Compile project.." an dialog is opened, but it is said:

> StockWatcher is not a GWT project.

The "Compile" button is also enable.

I clicked on Project/Browser.. but it shows an empty window.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Google plugin installed correctly, right click on your project in the package explorer.  There should be a Google Web Toolkit menu entry which allows you to convert your project into a GWT one.

Once the project has been converted you should be able to compile and debug your project as normal.

Answer (score 6):

Right-click on your project, `Google` > `Web Toolkit Settings...` > check `Use GWT`.

Same for AppEngine, if you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

In the project properties, you probably didn't enable the Google Web Toolkit feature.

Comment: thanks, but how I enable the GWT feature? I check Properties of the project but I didn't find it..

Comment: thanks bro, seems to be a bug in the Eclipse plugin I think!